# Pyhton 3 - are there cases where it's OK to alter the container you're looping on with a for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

In the following code I pass a list of an unknown number of inside lists to a function that sorts each inside list and then zips the lists and returns a list of the zip object.

```
def myZip (LS):
    for i in LS:
        i.sort()
    return list(zip(*LS))

        
L1=[3,1,2]
L2=[5,6,4]
L3=['a','b','c']
print(myZip([L1, L2, L3]))
```

I know it's a bad idea to alter the container you're looping on. My question is does this also apply to the situation I described here?

Comment: "*is it acceptable?*" Acceptable in *what way*? Does it meet your requirements? If so, why would it matter to you if someone deems it "*acceptable*" or not? The way it's currently phrased, your question is really much too opinion-based for Stack Overflow, questions of which type are off-topic here per the scope defined in the [help/on-topic]. See [ask]

Comment: @esqew I mean your problem with the question being too opinion-based is founded, but we all know the OP meant is it best practice/going to cause them problems now/later on.

Comment: "*we all know the OP meant is it best practice/going to cause them problems now/later on*" As the question currently reads, I can't say I agree entirely. If this is what the OP truly meant, they should indicate that directly by editing their question. Questions asking about best practice can also most times be opinion-based as well (as there isn't generally an authoritative source on such matters, and you will find lots of equally "correct" information on all sides of these issues) nor can we reliably predict in many cases whether such a design will "*cause them problems now/later on*".

Comment: Your code should behave as you intend.  This would only be a problem if the list contained itself, at the top level, which isn't something you normally need to worry about.  E.g. `x = [1, None, 3]; x[1] = x`.

Comment: You're not actually altering the iterated object, only the contents of the components. `LS` is still a list containing the same three lists (which have been updated).

Comment: I think OP is confusing the common rule. Its bad practice to edit the container that you're  actively iterating through, but in this case, OP is editing a nested container. You don't want to change the container being iterated through because that can result in partial (or unexpected) results being assigned to the loop variable. In this case I see no issue because the order of items in `LS` are not being edited, only their nested values.

Comment: If you wanted to do this without mutating `LS` then I would write: `list(zip(*map(sorted, LS)))`

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answers. I edited my question and erased "is it acceptable?". English is not my native language. I wrote my question as I did for lack of a better way to express what I'm asking.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The answer to your *Question* is no... I mean there are always exceptions, but the answer is still no; it's not a good idea, nor is it acceptable.

Now, the answer to the thing you typed after answering the *question* is perfectly fine, acceptable, etc. *Because* you aren't giving an example of altering the `container` you're looping through; rather, you are altering items in that list - which is pretty standard really.